# JavaScript removes all the css style information

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie to web development. And so, I've just created a sample webpage. It contains an html page, a css file and a JavaScript file. But whenever this JavaScript is linked to the html page, the css formattings are removed. This happens only after linking the JS file. If the same link is removed, css works fine. could u tell me the problem. i'm using windows xp sp3 and google chrome latest. is it the problem with the browser.

Here are my codes

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="all">
</head>
<body
<div>
<ul id="nav">
            <li id="click" <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li <a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li <a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li <a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li <a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var list = document.getElementById("nav")
list.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
switch(event.target.id) {
case "click":
document.title="I changed the document title";
break;
}, false);
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #071726;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
    background-color: #326773;
}
```

Comment: Open dev tools in your browser (like F12 in IE) and see if there is anything interesting in console (like "someone does not want to close curly braces")...

Comment: I'd recommend fixing your `<body>` opening tag - currently it's shown as `<body`, missing the ending brace `>`. **EDIT** Your `<li>` opening tags are also missing the ending brace.

Comment: i think there's a problem with the css. do u see any?

Comment: @user2899508 First fix your markup problems.

Comment: `body` and `li` tag is not closed..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not closing your link tag, it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="all" />
```

Now regarding your issue. I think you have a problem with the your JavaScript source. Ensure in development tools that your `<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>` actually returns a script - ensure that srs points to the correct location of the script

Answer (score 0):

Made this an answer, since [after testing in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUNHf/) and [comparing it to a fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/yUNHf/1/), I suspect it's the source of your problems:

I'd recommend fixing your `<body>` and `<li>` opening tags - currently they are being shown as `<body` and `<li` respectively, missing their ending braces (`>`).
This is what your HTML should look like after you fix the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="click"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but, clicking on the li with id click doesnt initiate what i wanted, to change the document title.

Comment: @user2899508 That could be for a number of reasons, but it's a different question entirely. (your Javascript loads before the DOM does, it `event.target.type` is `""`, etc.)

Comment: so, what should i do to load JavaScript after the DOM has been loaded. where am I supposed to place this link?

Comment: @user2899508 I don't mean to sound rude, but you should ask another question regarding why it isn't working to single out your issues.